# Bootstrapper Prerequisites not showing up

Tags: bootstrapper, prerequisites

I have a problem with Bootstrapper Prerequisites (with Bootstrapper Manifest Generator and doing it by hand...). I want to package Visual Power Packs 3.0 and Microsoft Sync 2.1 in one pack, so it appears in only one folder like (FinalApp_Prerequisites) along with the setup. The problem is that, only one of the 2 executables is detected, not both of them.

Here is my Product.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product ProductCode="FinalApp.Prerequisites" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="true">
    <PackageFile Name="synchronization-v2.1-x64-esn.msi" PublicKey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
    <PackageFile Name="visualbasicpowerpacks3setup.exe" PublicKey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
  </PackageFiles>
  <Commands Reboot="Defer">
    <Command PackageFile="synchronization-v2.1-x64-esn.msi">
      <ExitCodes>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
    <Command PackageFile="visualbasicpowerpacks3setup.exe">
      <ExitCodes>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
</Product>
```

And here is my Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package Name="DisplayName" Culture="Culture" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
  <Strings>
    <String Name="Culture">en</String>
    <String Name="DisplayName">FinalApp Prerequisites (Microsoft Synchronizer Framework 2.1 & Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0)</String>
    <String Name="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr">An unexpected exit code was returned from the installer. The installation failed.</String>
  </Strings>
</Package>
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it that I just can't put up 2 executables together as one prerequisite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both commands have a only a default exitcode which is fail. So when the bootstrapper runs, it will always detect the first installation to fail, so the second will not run any more. For example you can define that exitcode 0 means success:

```
<Command PackageFile="visualbasicpowerpacks3setup.exe">
  <ExitCodes>
    <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
    <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" String="Anunexpectedexitcodewasr" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" />
  </ExitCodes>
</Command>
```

Comment: That's okey. But why is my FinalAppPrerequisites not showing up in the Setup Prerequisites Project to check?

Comment: @user1867125 Where is it not showing up? Your package does not have any InstallChecks or InstallConditions, so I think it should always be executed.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the Setup Project Prerequisites to be checked. Shouldn't it appear in the checkbox list as "FinalAppPrerequisites"? So, as it doesn't appear in it, the setup doesn't install the prerequisites...

Comment: @Sweeden Did you correctly store the files in `\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)). Also, try to modify an existing bootstrapper package, changing one step at a time.

Comment: Yes, it was placed correctly. In fact, when I put them separately (one product.xml and package.xml for Sync Framework, and one product and package for Power Packs 3.0), it will appear in the Prerequisites, but if I "pack" or "put them together" as one requisites, so there is an unique folder and appear as an only one prerequisite, it doesn't show up in the menu.

Comment: Then I don't know what is wrong. If I look at the DotNetFX40 bootstrapper created by microsoft, it also has two `<PackageFile>`'s and two `<Command>`'s, so it is the same as you are doing...

Comment: May it has something to do the fact that the DotNetFX40 has only one executable, and my FinalAppPrerequisites, has two? (Sync and PowerPacks)

Comment: DotNetFX40 has two executables on my pc (`dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe` and `dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe`). You have to [manually download one of the executables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12148234/33499).

Comment: Ok, I will try then to copy and modify the DotNetFX40 files. I will comment my results in a few minutes. By the way, thanks for the help given by this time.

Comment: After doing it, and copying it also in v6.0A and v8.0A it appeared. Thanks for your help!