# Error found while publishing a window based application

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I have made a project on stationery management system ! whenever I am trying to publish it.

It is producing errors like

> Error 2   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my
>   application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file
>   'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' for item 'Microsoft .NET
>   Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' to your local machine.
>
> error 1 To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my
>   application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file
>   'SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe' for item 'SQL
>   Server Compact 4.0 SP1' to your local machine.
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.    Stationary_Management
>
> Error 3   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my
>   application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file
>   'SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe' for item 'SQL
>   Server Compact 4.0 SP1' to your local machine. For more information,
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883.

Please help to solve this.

Comment: I copy and pasted part of your last error (From "Download" to "Edition") into google and this is the [first stack overflow link that appeared for me](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15436991/1324033)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re publish the application with the following changes
[image: is it your current selection?]

At this point select the second radio button **Download prerequisties from the same location as my application** then press ok to continue.

Comment: mention not please, indicate that the answer is right by tick so that it will became a reference for others also

Comment: but My problem remain same !!! i want my exe execute in any other system also !! it is getting loaded but wen it trying to fetch data from Database! get failed !!! so i need solution for this !!!!! 
front end: VS 2012
Back ENd : sql server 2008

Comment: that's a different problem so ask it as a different question