# Error after upgrading to VS 2013 in deployment project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, deployment-project

I recently installed VS 2013 in an attempt to upgrade the solution I work on from VS 2010. The solution seems to mostly work correctly except for a deployment project that it contains.

I am getting an error very similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436991/in-visual-studio-2012-where-does-clickonce-publish-expect-to-find-the-net-4-c/15438677#15438677). The only difference being that that question is dealing with the clint profile and I am dealing with the full install of .Net 4.0.

The distinction between that question and mine is that they are dealing with a click-once app and I am dealing with a deployment project. I tried the solutions listed there anyway and there was no change.

Part of the error discusses an option to "download prerequisites from the same location as the application." However, in 2013 I am not even seeing that option anywhere.

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

--Jacob

P.S.: I did install the necessary add-on to add deployment project support in 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question I referred to suggested putting the installer package into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\**v8.0A**\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40Client"

I found that it worked when I used "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\**v8.1A**\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40Client" then it worked correctly.

**Also note:** In my question I said I am using the full version and in my answer I refer to the client profile. In the course of working on this we switched from one to the other, but that didn't matter in the solution except that the path for the full version is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\**v8.1A**\Bootstrapper\Packages\**DotNetFX40**".